# In GAS (google apps script), I am using supposedly correct code, but text is not being replaced like it should be. Why?

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first  time ever asking anything on this site. My question is simple; I'm constructing, in GAS, a script to replace spelled numbers (seven, one, eight, etc.) with single-character ones (7, 1, 8 respectively etc.). My code is designed to use bodyElement.replaceText('', ''); method to replace this text. (see below) As well as an input box to let the user type in the text to be replaced. The script runs without errors, except that it does not replace the text! The Documentation alert box works fine, the Cancel button on the number replacer works fine, but the replacing itself doesn't occur. Script:

```js
function rNumber () {
  var bodyElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var one ="1";
  var two ="2";
  var three ="3";
  var four ="4";
  var five ="5";
  var six ="6";
  var seven ="7";
  var eight ="8";
  var nine ="9";
  var ten ="10";
  var result = DocumentApp.getUi().prompt('Please enter the number', DocumentApp.getUi().ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  // Process the number and doit
  // Process the user's response:
  if (result.getSelectedButton() == DocumentApp.getUi().Button.YES) {
    // The user clicked the "OK" button.
    if (result.getSelectedText == "one") {
    bodyElement.replaceText('one', '1');
    }
  } else if (result.getSelectedButton() == DocumentApp.getUi().Button.NO) {
    // The user clicked the "Cancel" button.
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('No number was selected.');
  }
}
```

halp

Comment: I didn't test but I think you should use document.saveAndClose() at the end of the function to update the document.

Comment: You're missing the brackets on `result.getSelectedText()`. AND you probably meant `getResponseText()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `result.getResponseText()`, not `result.getSelectedText`. Make sure to use the correct function name and to add parentheses when calling a function.

Here's a modified version of your function. I had some fun with it and made it a little cleaner and more robust. Ask me questions by adding comments to this answer if you need me to explain anything.

```
function replace() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var numbers = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", 
      "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"];

  var result = DocumentApp.getUi().prompt('Enter a number.',
      DocumentApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  var text = result.getResponseText();

  if (result.getSelectedButton() == DocumentApp.getUi().Button.CANCEL) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('You pressed cancel.');
    return;
  }

  if (numbers.indexOf(text) === -1) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('I can\'t replace that number.');
    return;
  }

  body.replaceText(text, numbers.indexOf(text));
}
```